# Javascript code design: how to try catch each line in a good way?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, try-catch

My goal is to catch the error of each line and even there is an error, still run the remaining code, like this:

```
try {
  doFirstThing()
} catch(err) {
  //not important
}
try {
  doSecondThing()
} catch(err) {
  //not important
}
try {
  doSecondThing()
} catch(err) {
  //not important
}
//...
try {
  doLastThing()
} catch(err) {
  //not important
}
```

My question is: Do I have to try-catch each line to do this? Or there is a clever equivalent way that can have this done in a more elegant manner?

Comment: no, that's the only way to do it if do***thing throws errors

Comment: Why do you need separate `try..catch` for each line? are going to handle each catch in different way? or it is fine to have a single catch error in either of function call?

Comment: @Harish because I want all other lines to still be running if any of these lines (or even multiple) throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

If all the code you want to run is contained in functions, you could do:

```
[doFirstThing, doSecondThing, doThirdThing, doLastThing].forEach(thing => {
  try {
    thing();
  } catch(err) {}
};
```